# Compiler error appending slice to slice

Tags: go

The Go compiler is complaining about my code to append a slice to a slice. Here are relevant excerpts:

```
type LanidEntry struct {
    lanid   string
    group   string
    contact string
}

var lanids []LanidEntry

func load_file() (lanids_loaded []LanidEntry, errormsgs string) {
    // ...
}

func Load() (lanids []LanidEntry, errormessages string) {
    lanids_loaded, errormsgs := load_file(filename1, contact1)
    lanids = append(lanids, lanids_loaded)
    // ...
}
```

The `append` line generates this compiler message:

```
 src\load_lanids\load_lanids.go:50: cannot use lanids_loaded (type []LanidEntry) as type LanidEntry in append
```

I know that appending slices to slices works fine, based on an example in [a Go Blog post](https://blog.golang.org/slices#TOC_10.)
under the section headed **Append: The built-in function**.

Comment: `lanids = append(lanids, lanids_loaded...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `...`:

```
lanids = append(lanids, lanids_loaded...)
```

Also, also please format your code :)

You should also read [Slice Tricks](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks) on the Wiki.

Comment: @KevinBuchs yep gofmt. I recommend GoSublime if you use sublimetext or go-plus for atom or vim-go for well, vim.